# How terminate a thread while I using WaitForMultipleObjects

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a secondary thead (`TMyWaitFor`) on my application which executes a few worker threads (`TFooThr`) and wait for the finalization of these threads using the `WaitForMultipleObjects`  function

this is the relevant code

```
const
 nThreads=5;
//these arrays are declarated in the private section of the TMyWaitFor thread  
 tArr  : Array[1..nThreads]  of TFooThr;
 hArr  : Array[1..nThreads]  of THandle;

procedure TMyWaitFor.Execute;
Var
 i     : Integer;
begin
  for i:=1  to nThreads do
   begin
     tArr[i]:=TFooThr.Create(AValue);
     hArr[i]:=tArr[i].Handle;
   end;

  WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreads, @hArr[0], True, INFINITE);
end;
```

All works ok , but now In some situations, I can't wait for the threads (TFooThr) and I need cancel the operation, so I need to stop (terminate) all the threads which I started in the `TMyWaitFor.Execute` , so the quesion is `How I can terminate all TFooThr threads started the Execute method of the TMyWaitFor thread?`

Comment: To terminate TFooThr threads at any moment requires support from TFooThr.Execute method, not from TMyWaitFor.Execute.

Comment: @Serg I really knew that. The original problem was how bypass the WaitForMultipleObjects function to call the terminate method of each child thread, but now that was fixed with the Nat answer.

Comment: I don't see a reason to call the terminate methods of child threads from TMyWaitFor.Execute - you can implement these calls as a public method of TMyWaitFor class (though most probably you will call it from the main thread).

Comment: @Serg +1 That is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David suggested, call Terminated on the thread and change your code to check the terminated flag regularly:

```
procedure TMyWaitFor.Execute;
Var
  i     : Integer;
begin
  for i:=1  to nThreads do
  begin
    tArr[i]:=TFooThr.Create(AValue);
    hArr[i]:=tArr[i].Handle;
  end;

  while not Terminated do
    //wait half a second
    if WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreads, @hArr[0], True, 500) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT then 
      Break; 
end;
```

**Update 2011-08-03**

David and Serg are correct I'm afraid and I am incorrect. In TFooThr.Execute you should be checking for Terminated. In the main thread of your application, you can call Terminate on all the TFooThr's to kill them, and as long as they are taking notice of the Terminated flag, then TMyWaitFor will fall through all by itself.

You should remove your acceptance of this answer.

N@

Comment: You need to be more careful with the return value from `WaitForMultipleObjects`. At the very least you need to put it into a variable for further inspection.

Comment: Thanks Nat I rewrote the code using your suggestion and works ok.

Comment: It is usually somewhat inefficient to use a timeout based solution like this. Such problems can be always be solved without doing so in a more elegant way.

Comment: I don't see how it answers the OP question - `How I can terminate all TFooThr threads`.

Comment: @David Can you offer a better solution then? I posted something that works for me, but I'm always open to better ideas. And yes, I realise that the return value should be dealt with a bit better. I'll update my answer.

Comment: As Serg said, calling Terminate of each sub-thread from a different thread, e.g. the main thread which which is presumably what received the instruction to cancel the operation. Your code can wait half second wait before starting to terminate. If you reduce the timeout to make it more responsive then you just burn clock cycles transitioning into and out of kernel mode.

Comment: You are correct. I seem to have miss-read the questing. I will remove my answer.

Comment: Oh, I can't. Is there any way I can force it? Otherwise I will update my answer and at least give credit to you in and Serg in there.

Comment: @Nat You can't remove the accepted answer. That can sometimes be embarassing if it attracts lots of down votes as happened once to me!!

Comment: @David Yes, you've got to be careful of those 'downvoters'... Well, at least I've mentioned it in the answer. Maybe the OP will come back and remove his acceptance...